# Isa server 2006 proxy chaining : How to chain only HTTP traffic?

Tags: proxy, isa-server

I am trying to configure ISA server 2006 to chain all HTTP request to another proxy (which propose compression services). But this proxy don't support HTTPS traffic. For the moment, I use the web chaining feature in ISA and the HTTP traffic works with no problem but HTTPS doesn't work. Indeed, when I specify that I want forward my traffic to another server, It ask me a ssl port, which doesn't exists and ISA refuse validation if the field is empty.
So, how to configure ISA to chain all HTTP traffic but not chain the HTTPS traffic ?

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can select from ISA firewall the connection then at listner select http and delete the https listner (or disable it ).

To be on the safe side , do a export configuration from the \right click on isa \ Export(Back Up) .

Regards,
Aex H